# Angular2 http post couln't catch controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, angular, asp.net-core

I would like to call post asp net core controller action.

Here's my code:
Message Controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class MessageController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult AddBlog(string email)
    {
        //test
        return View();
    }
}
```

my form:

```
<form [formGroup]="contactForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmitModelBased()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" formControlName="email" placeholder="email">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Wyślij</button>
</form>
```

and my component ts

```
public onSubmitModelBased() {
    alert("test");
    let body = JSON.stringify({ email: 'test@test.pl' });
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    this.http
        .post('/api/Message/AddBlog', body, { headers: headers })
        .subscribe(data => {
            alert('ok');
        }, error => {
            alert('not ok');
        });
}
```

I; seeing alert("test") and the http.post action return alert('ok').
I've also made a breakpoint in controller action but it hasn't been catched there.

Comment: can you include the contents of your `Startup.cs` file?

Comment: @Danoram Which part of startup.cs do you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your routing should be:

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public class MessageController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult AddBlog([FromBody] AddBlogModel model)
    {
        //test
        return View();
    }
}
```

The way you have it set up now means the action is hit when a POST request comes to /api/message. Adding the action placeholder makes it accept POST requests to /api/message/addblog as you intended.

EDIT: As for your other problem, you are sending a JSON object but expecting MVC to figure it out. You will need to make a model class such as:

```
public class AddBlogModel
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

And change your controller action as above. This will tell MVC Core that the model should be created based on the request body, which is your JSON. The model contains a single property that will contain the email address.

Comment: Now I'm getting POST http://localhost:57572/api/Message/AddBlog 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: See my edit, at least you have to define a view model for the data. If it's not that then you have to check the logs.

Comment: How can I put some logs with angular? Now I'm having alert('not ok');

Comment: Use your browser F12 tools to see what the server is returning.

Comment: The problem was with my services which has not been configured well. Thanks for your help !